# Can I force git to use TLS only?

Tags: git, networking, ssl

When I use git under a specific network environment, it will send out SSL packet rather than TLS one, and says "`gnutls_hanshake() failed(): A TLS packet with unexpected length was receive`” . This is the only difference I can discover from the WireShark logs between them:

**The SUCCESS result**

[image]

**The FAILED result**

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, x86-64 version. And this problem appeared also on MacBook and 11.10 problem. But when I try with Win7 and Git Gui, it got no errors.

And if I switch to other network environments, like pppoe in my home, or the WiFi in some cafe, the problem disappeared with my Ubuntu 12.04 ( same settings, same OS ).

Please help me to know what can I do. At least if I have to argue this problem with my MIS, I can figure out why this shouldn't happen.

Thanks !

PS.1. I have tried the solution listed in [ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67935/issues-checking-out-code-from-google-code), but it didn't work.

PS.2. [Filezilla seemed had this problem](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23205), too. But I can't find how they solve the problem ( and apply to git ).

Answer (score 0):

Git uses libcurl for HTTP connections.

I am not aware of any runtime configuration of the library (which it might have), but you might be able to modify the Git itself to force it to use TLS-only connections. Checkout http.c. The libcurl function for the purpose should be curl_easy_setopt with argument CURLOPT_SSLVERSION with CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1.

Comment: That would be the function "static CURL *get_curl_handle(void)" in the mentioned http.c (FWIW now)